# How to connect to Postgres using SSH and PHP?

Tags: php, postgresql, ssh

I need to connect to a Postgres table on a server that requires SSH to access. Does anyone know a way?

I have attempted to to use sshpass:

`sshpass -p 'PASSWORD' ssh -f -L 5433:127.0.0.1:5432 USERNAME@SERVER -N`

And then I attempted to connect with pg_connect:

`pg_connect('host=localhost port=5432 dbname=DATABASE user=USERNAME password=PASSWORD')`

But `pg_connect` just returns `false` with no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I (almost) had it right but I was using the wrong port in the pg_connect. I should have been using port 5433, since that is what I used with sshpass.

Proper Solution:

I need to connect to a Postgres table on a server that requires SSH to access. Does anyone know a way?

Execute:
`sshpass -p 'PASSWORD' ssh -f -L 5433:127.0.0.1:5432 USERNAME@SERVER -N`

pg_connect:
`pg_connect('host=localhost port=5433 dbname=DATABASE user=USERNAME password=PASSWORD')`